# How to use map for multiple conditions

Tags: haskell

is it possible to use `map` with multiply condition. For example a `list [1,-2,3,-4]`
it should `+1` for all `<0` and `*2` for `>0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` itself can only apply the same function to each element of the list, but the *function* can decide how to operate on each element.

For example, if we write a function to double all odd numbers and add 100 to all even numbers:

```
myFunc x | odd x     = 2 * x
         | otherwise = 100 + x
```

we can apply that function using `map`:

```
> map myFunc [1..4]
[2,102,6,104]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a bit ugly, but works:

```
map (\x -> if x < 0 then x+1 else x*2) [1,-2,3,-4,0]
```